# What to do if someone keeps adding me to a Trello board without my knowledge?

Tags: trello, security, spam-prevention, trello-boards

I am thinking about creating a team project, but unfortunately my team members can't visit me often as they are far away from my home. So I'll be needing a secure, free, team management software, and I came across Trello. Adding members to Trello seems too easy, that I really think I have to ask about it here. I was reading this: http://help.trello.com/article/717-adding-people-to-a-board and realized that just choosing someone by name is enough to add them into our board.

Because there is no "invitation" system, where a Trello board admin sends a message inviting a participant and the participant having to accept the invitation to join the board, people can anonymously add others into a Trello board and literally "spam" them with messages.

Isn't it insecure to be able to add anyone without their permission?

Answer (score 2):

When you add someone to a board they have to accept before seeing your cards. They will receive a notification that you have invited them, and you will receive a notification when they have accepted. Those invitations should also be in your board's history.

You can change the settings of a board to only allow team admins to add members: **Show menu > Settings > Invitations Permissions**

[Trello Business Class](http://help.trello.com/article/714-business-class-user-guide#Board-invitation-permissions) has more finely-tuned options for member access; it might be more suited to your needs.

I hope this helps!

Comment: "they have to accept before seeing your cards" This does not appear to be quite correct - I was added to a very explicit Trello board without having to respond to any invitation - it just showed up in my list of Trello boards.

Comment: I was added to a board, chose to decline, still shows up!